# Convert a series of lists into a single list

Tags: python, pandas

I need to take a series that looks like the following where the rows are labelled A-D and the column I am interested in is called `vals` and consists of a `list` of integer values of varying length (but will never be null):

```
A                                            [1, 140]
B                                            [345, 567]
C                                            [400, 45, 12]
D                                            [1]
```

And convert it into a series that is just a single list that might look like (I no longer care about the row label at this point):

```
0                                            [1, 140, 345, 567, 400, 45, 12, 1]
```

I am not sure how to do this, what I have tried so far is unsuccessful as it gives me a list of lists which is not what I want, but I will add this below as I might be somewhere in the right region.

```
single_list = s.groupby(lambda x: True).apply(list).agg({"vals": list})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), but slowier if large DataFrame:

```
L = list(df['vals'].explode())
```

Or flatten values should be faster in large df:

```
L = [y for x in df['vals'] for y in x])
```

Comment: I opted for `explode()` and then converted back to a series, many thanks again. Explode seemed a slightly tidier solution and I was able to do it with comprehension already but wanted to try to keep it as "pandas" as possible, if that makes sense.